# Получить сырой SQL из Django ORM запроса, который использует aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, django-orm

Подскажите как достать SQL из вот такой строки кода:

```
q = Book.objects.aggregate(price_avg=Avg('price'))
```

Comment: Попробуйте `print(q.query)` `print(q.query.as_sql())`

Comment: Пробовал. Смысл в том, что результатом запроса является словарь.
'dict' object has no attribute 'query'

Comment: А если сделать логирование? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835465/5909792

Comment: Можно конечно, я просто хотел sql писать в переменную и записывать в результат

Comment: Наверно придется использовать: from django.db import connection